# Problems with downloading PDF from WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi backend. From my client (TypeScript) I send form data to this backend, which will use that data to fill in a PDF form and return the data from the PDF form (do not want to store the filled-in PDFs as they will take up a lot of space, so after I have created a temp PDF with all the fields filled in, I read the data and then remove the temp file). I did this in MVC a few years ago, and simply returned a File response from the controller. But in WebApi, I am unable to find an equivalent of this.

In my controller, I do the following:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfData);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(DispositionTypeNames.Attachment) { FileName = pdfWriter.PdfName };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = (long)pdfData.Length;

                return response;
```

pdfWriter is my class that fills in the PDF form. It returns the PDF form data and holds the name of the PDF that should be downloaded.

In my client, I have tried various alternatives found on this very site, but I am unable to get it to work as I want: getting a file download prompt.

I tried to create a blob and open the blob in a new window, like so:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            try {
                var blob = new Blob([data]);
                window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
            }
            catch (ex) {
            }
        }
    };
```

But that opened the window showing the actual PDF data...

I tried another suggestion on this site:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            try {
                var blob = new Blob([data]);
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "filled-in-form.pdf";
                link.click();
            }
            catch (ex) {
            }
        }
    };
```

But that produced two problems: Firstly, .download does not exist on HTMLAnchorElement according to my compiler. So I removed that, but then the code simply does the same as the above code, opens the actual PDF data in another window.

Is there any other solution I can try here?

Comment: Why are you using AJAX to download a file from the server? Put a simple `<a>` tag with `href` pointing to your controller action. When clicked, the browser will show the Save as dialog. And if you need to pass some data to the action then use a `<form>` with its `action` pointing to your action. In this case a simple submit button will do the job.

Comment: Great, your idea worked really well. Thank you.